# Joomla search module

Tags: search, joomla

I want to search module like this site.
http://www.carsales.com.au/all-cars/results.aspx?N=1216+1246+1247+1252+1282&keywords=&tsrc=allcarhome&Nne=15

Im want to know that how i develope this type of component?
or if any body know direct componet so plz tell me
 its urgent

Answer (score 0):

If you need a component that does autos for sale listings look here - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/vehicles